I get a blank page when I try to access my site on iOS
i'm actually working on an app built with reactJs, i can access it from all the platforms
(Fedora, Android, Windows, Mac OS), but on iPhone I just get a blank page, with this error.
Versions:
react: v18.2.0
iOS: v17.5.1
Host: Hostinger
website URL: https://obogo.bbssolutions.fr



Any help about where it comes from or how i can debug it would be really appreciated.

please provide a minimal code.
use screenshots and describe your images.
write your given errors in a console.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It seems that an error occured while uploading the files.
Now they should be well available.

Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.
